# Android - pass OAuth1 in HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android, oauth, httpsurlconnection

I am new to OAuth concept, I am trying to achieve this

I need to hit a Url with consumer key, consumer secret, user token and user secret using HttpsURLConnection

Here is my code snippet:

```
String endpointURL = "some_dummy_url";
URL url = new URL(endpointURL);
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application-json");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

String consumerKey = getConsumerKey();
String consumerSecret = getConsumerSecret();
String usertoken  = getUserToken();
String userSecret = getUserTokenSecret();

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", //pass the tokens);

connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String consumerKey = getConsumerKey();
String consumerSecret = getConsumerSecret();

String baseAuthStr = consumerKey + ":" + consumerSecret;
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + baseAuthStr);
```

**Thanks to this** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402704/1283715).

**Update**

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=" + your_api_key);
URLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.addRequestProperty("client_id", usertoken);
conn.addRequestProperty("client_secret", userSecret);


String token = consumerKey + ":" + consumerSecret;
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
String encodedString = encoder.encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) );
//conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
```

**Reference** [doc](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/id-auth/authenticate.html).

Comment: how to add the user token and user secret in the property?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43332091/1283715) to add token after build connection with `Authorization`.